# Printing character pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers

I was learning pointers in C when I wrote the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    char *p = 0;
    *p = 'a';
    printf("value in pointer p is %c\n", *p);
}
```

When I compiled the code, It was compiled successfully. Although, when I executed its `out` file, a runt-time error occurred: `Segmentation Fault (core dumped)`

I couldn't understand why that run-time error occurred. After all, the pointer `p` was pointing to character `a`, and thus the output should've been `a`.

Although, when I wrote the following code, it compiled and ran successfully:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main ()
{
    char *p = 0;
    char output = 'a';
    p = &output;
    printf("value which pointer p points is %c\n", *p);
}
```

Can someone explain me why the first program fails, while the second program runs successfully?

Comment: Please, read more books and C examples and then ask beginner's questions.

Comment: There is no explanation needed here, at least not one which you can't find it inside all books and tutorials. Just learn what is the difference between `*p` and `p`. That's all.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your code invokes undefined behavior because you are dereferencing a `NULL`<sup>1</sup> pointer. A pointer needs to point to valid memory, a simple way to achieve what you want is this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int // `main()' MUST return `int'
main(void)
{
    char *pointer;
    char value;

    pointer = &value; // Now the pointer points to valid memory
    *pointer = 'a';

    printf("value in pointer p is %c\n", *pointer);
    return 0;
}
```

---

> <sup>1</sup>
>   **6.3.2.3 Pointers**
>
> 3. An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type `void *`, is called a null pointer constant. <sup>66)</sup> If a null pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>66)</sup><sub>The macro `NULL` is defined in  (and other headers) as a null pointer constant; see 7.19.</sub>
>
> **6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators**
>
> **Semantics**
>
> 4. The unary `*` operator denotes indirection. If the operand points to a function, the result is a function designator; if it points to an object, the result is an lvalue designating the object. If the operand has type ‘‘pointer to type’’, the result has type ‘‘type’’. If an invalid value has been assigned to the pointer, the behavior of the unary * operator is undefined.<sup>102)</sup>
>
> ---
>
> <sup>102)</sup><sub>Thus, `&*E` is equivalent to `E` (even if `E` is a null pointer), and `&(E1[E2])` to `((E1)+(E2))`. It is always true that if E is a function designator or an lvalue that is a valid operand of the unary `&` operator, `*&E` is a function designator or an *lvalue* equal to `E`. If `*P` is an lvalue and T is the name of an object pointer type, `*(T)P` is an *lvalue* that has a type compatible with that to which `T` points.</sub>
>
> <sub>Among the invalid values for dereferencing a pointer by the unary `*` operator are a null pointer, an address inappropriately aligned for the type of object pointed to, and the address of an object after the end of its lifetime.</sub>

Comment: What do you mean by _"dereferencing"_?

Comment: This `*p` in `printf("value in pointer p is %c\n", *p);` *dereferences* the pointer. The pointer is a reference so you are de*referenc*ing or accessing the data the pointer points to, which in this case doesn't exist as the pointer is not pointing to any data.

Comment: So in my program 1, the pointer does not point to anything? Shouldn't it point to character 'a'?

Comment: No, it should point to memory where you can store the character `'a'` see the edit.

Comment: A pointer variable "points" at another variable. That is, given: `char v; char *p;` then `p = &v;` sets `p` to `v`s address ("points at v").  To deference `p` (`*p`) is to access what is in the variable it points at (`v` in this case). So, `*p = 'x';` puts the character 'x' in `v` and `printf("%c", *p);` will print whatever character is in `v` ('x' in this example).

Comment: Thanks, @JohnHascall, your comment really helped. Also, thanks iharob.

Comment: Long ago I saw an HP C compiler with a command-line option to define the void pointer as any specific address. I ran the other direction. 99.9999% of the time it will be zero but lets be careful out there.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, you set `p` to 0, which on most implementations is the same as `NULL`.  You then attempt to dereference that pointer (read/write the memory location that `p` points to), which leads to the core dump.  `p` is *not* pointing to the character `a`.  This `*p = 'a'` says "take the memory location that `p` points to and put `a` there".

In the second example, you're setting `p` to the address of `output`, so it points to a known memory location.  Then when you dereference is, you're reading the value at the location where `p` points, i.e. `output`.  This is valid usage.

Comment: I think it's mandatory that a `NULL` pointer is `(void *) 0x00`, read section 6.3.2.3 paragraph 3 of the C11 standard draft.

Comment: `says "take the memory location that p points to and put a there".` That's happens because of  `*` in front of `*p` but not also when you say `p = "a"`. Basically this means that he need to understand the diffprence between `*p` and `*`

Answer (score 1):

A pointer is a "special" variables that store the address of another variables. Take a look at this program, I hope that it will help you clarifying what a pointer is and how to use it :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

        int x = 10, *pointer = 0;

        pointer = &x;

        printf("\nThe address of x : %p.\n", &x);
        printf("\nThe address of the  pointer : %p.\n", pointer);

        printf("\nThe value of x : %d.\n", x);

        *pointer += 10;

        printf("\nThe value of x after we modifed it with the pointer : %d.\n\n", x);

return 0;

}
```

If you compile and give this program a run, this will be its output:

The address of x : 0xbf912108.

The address of the  pointer : 0xbf912108.

The value of x : 10.

The value of x after we modifed it with the pointer : 20.

As you can clearly see the address of the pointer is the same of the variable itself. That's why when you modify a pointer (for example in my program I do `*pointer += 10`) it's actually modifying the variable.

Comment: Don't treat a pointer like a `special variable`. A pointer is a variable like any other. Only different thing what does from "regular" variable is that a pointer doesn't hold a value, it holds a memory address of another variable.

Comment: @Michi That's exactly what I said. By the way, "special" is in quotes

Comment: My point was, based on the Question, that you should explain that the main difference is using `*p` and when and using `p` and when.